# Iterating through rows to see which value comes first

Tags: python, pandas

When working with Pandas I am able to check prior and following rows to see if certain conditions are met using .shift().

What if I need to see if a condition is met which could be 100 rows or more after the row I am comparing with?  I know looping through a dataframe is not the most efficient but can someone please help with the following example.

When the df['reversal'] column has a signal - as per the example below showing 6.0 at 14:00 - I want to know which one of the following is seen first after the row at 14:00 :

- `df.price` with value of `df.reversal` + 1 (we can see this was hit at 20:00 as 6 + 1 = 7)
- `df.price` with a value of `df.reversal` - `df.reversal` (this was not hit in this example as price did not hit 6 - 6 = 0)

[image: revimage]

This is the desired output with cells in Blue showing what I would like to see.  The new columns should show the time that target is hit (as per this example) or target missed (if price hits 0 in this example).

[image: des out]

Please see `df.to_dict()` below to reproduce:

```
{'move_start': {datetime.time(9, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(10, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(11, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(12, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(13, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(14, 0): datetime.time(9, 0),
  datetime.time(15, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(16, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(17, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(18, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(19, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(20, 0): nan},
 'price': {datetime.time(9, 0): 1,
  datetime.time(10, 0): 2,
  datetime.time(11, 0): 3,
  datetime.time(12, 0): 4,
  datetime.time(13, 0): 5,
  datetime.time(14, 0): 6,
  datetime.time(15, 0): 5,
  datetime.time(16, 0): 4,
  datetime.time(17, 0): 3,
  datetime.time(18, 0): 2,
  datetime.time(19, 0): 4,
  datetime.time(20, 0): 7},
 'reversal': {datetime.time(9, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(10, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(11, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(12, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(13, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(14, 0): 6.0,
  datetime.time(15, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(16, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(17, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(18, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(19, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(20, 0): nan}}
```

Comment: Would also be interesting to see how others aproach this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it nicer and cleaner, thought...

```
import datetime,numpy as np,pandas as pd
nan = np.nan

a = pd.DataFrame({'move_start': {datetime.time(9, 0): nan,   datetime.time(10, 0): nan,   datetime.time(11, 0): nan,   datetime.time(12, 0): nan,   datetime.time(13, 0): nan,   datetime.time(14, 0): datetime.time(9, 0),   datetime.time(15, 0): nan,   datetime.time(16, 0): nan,   datetime.time(17, 0): nan,   datetime.time(18, 0): nan,   datetime.time(19, 0): nan,   datetime.time(20, 0): nan},  'price': {datetime.time(9, 0): 1,   datetime.time(10, 0): 0,   datetime.time(11, 0): 3,   datetime.time(12, 0): 4,   datetime.time(13, 0): 7,   datetime.time(14, 0): 6,   datetime.time(15, 0): 5,   datetime.time(16, 0): 4,   datetime.time(17, 0): 0,   datetime.time(18, 0): 2,   datetime.time(19, 0): 4,   datetime.time(20, 0): 7},  'reversal': {datetime.time(9, 0): nan,   datetime.time(10, 0): nan,   datetime.time(11, 0): nan,   datetime.time(12, 0): nan,   datetime.time(13, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(14, 0): 6.0,   datetime.time(15, 0): nan,   datetime.time(16, 0): nan,   datetime.time(17, 0): nan,   datetime.time(18, 0): nan,   datetime.time(19, 0): nan,   datetime.time(20, 0): nan}})


a['target_hit']=nan;
a['target_miss']=nan;
a['reversal1']=a['reversal']+1;
a['reversal2']=a['reversal']-a['reversal'];
a.sort_index(1,inplace=True);

hit = a.ix[:,:-2].dropna()

takeBoth = False
targetIsHit,targetIsMiss = False,False

if takeBoth:

    targetHit = a[(hit['reversal1'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal1'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)];
    targetMiss = a[(hit['reversal2'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal2'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)];

    targetIsHit,targetIsMiss = not targetHit.empty, not targetMiss.empty

else:

    targetHit = a[(hit['reversal1'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal1'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)];
    targetIsHit = not targetHit.empty
    if not targetIsHit:
         targetMiss = a[(hit['reversal2'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal2'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)]; 
         targetIsMiss = not targetMiss.empty

if targetIsHit:a.loc[hit.index.values,"target_hit"] = targetHit.index.values;
if targetIsMiss:a.loc[hit.index.values,"target_miss"] = targetMiss.index.values;

print '#'*50
print a
'''
##################################################
         move_start  price  reversal  reversal1  reversal2 target_hit  \
09:00:00        NaN      1       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
10:00:00        NaN      0       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
11:00:00        NaN      3       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
12:00:00        NaN      4       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
13:00:00        NaN      7       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
14:00:00   09:00:00      6       6.0        7.0        0.0   20:00:00   
15:00:00        NaN      5       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
16:00:00        NaN      4       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
17:00:00        NaN      0       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
18:00:00        NaN      2       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
19:00:00        NaN      4       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
20:00:00        NaN      7       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

          target_miss  
09:00:00          NaN  
10:00:00          NaN  
11:00:00          NaN  
12:00:00          NaN  
13:00:00          NaN  
14:00:00          NaN  
15:00:00          NaN  
16:00:00          NaN  
17:00:00          NaN  
18:00:00          NaN  
19:00:00          NaN  
20:00:00          NaN
'''
```

PS: As typical pythonist Im lazy and like to work on plain input/output containing most typical problems, so You make it nasty df from beggining, not only write about it XD... About reading text... People tends to write, write and write. Usually its simple problem, but hella wroten, so I dont understand a yota xD. Then its like "WTF did he want here?!".

Comment: Hi Robert, It looked like your code had solved this but unfortunately when I change the `10:00` `a.price` cell to `0` your code looks backwards and uses this as the `target_miss`.  It is important that only future rows are considered.  Can you please look at this?  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Also I needed to change the first `if not` to an `if` to get any output as follows: `if targetMiss.empty:a.loc[hit.index.values,"target_hit"] = targetHit.index.values;`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Ahh sry I was sleeping xD... w8 I will check it

Comment: There was bug... It should be `if not targetHit:...` and `if not targetMiss:...` I was copying line `if not targetMiss:...` to make line `if not targetHit:...` and changed everything properly but not `targetMiss` to `targetHit`...

Comment: But should target hit be only post target miss, and miss never after hit?

Comment: Yes you are right that it should only give a `targetHit` or a `targetMiss` and not both at same time.  Once one target is reached it is done.  Is this an easy fix for you?  thank you for the help!

Comment: There is an issue when hit has more than one row.  It is beyond the scope of this question though so I have asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042148/operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-error-when-two-rows-used