# Operands could not be broadcast together error when two rows used

Tags: python, pandas

Working with the following data:

```
import datetime,numpy as np,pandas as pd
nan = np.nan

a = pd.DataFrame(  {'price': {datetime.time(9, 0): 1,   datetime.time(10, 0): 0,   datetime.time(11, 0): 3,   datetime.time(12, 0): 4,   datetime.time(13, 0): 7,   datetime.time(14, 0): 6,   datetime.time(15, 0): 5,   datetime.time(16, 0): 4,   datetime.time(17, 0): 0,   datetime.time(18, 0): 2,   datetime.time(19, 0): 4,   datetime.time(20, 0): 7},  'reversal': {datetime.time(9, 0): 1,   datetime.time(10, 0): nan,   datetime.time(11, 0): nan,   datetime.time(12, 0): nan,   datetime.time(13, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(14, 0): 6.0,   datetime.time(15, 0): nan,   datetime.time(16, 0): nan,   datetime.time(17, 0): nan,   datetime.time(18, 0): nan,   datetime.time(19, 0): nan,   datetime.time(20, 0): nan}})


a['target_hit']=nan;
a['target_miss']=nan;
a['reversal1']=a['reversal']+1;
a['reversal2']=a['reversal']-a['reversal'];
a.sort_index(1,inplace=True);
```

I create a subset as follows:

```
hit = a.ix[:,:-2].dropna()
hit
```

Which gives output showing two rows that match:

```
         price  reversal  reversal1 reversal2
 09:00:00   1   1.0         2.0     0.0
 14:00:00   6   6.0         7.0     0.0
```

When I then try to use these rows to match against the following I get this error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (12,)`

```
takeBoth = False
targetIsHit,targetIsMiss = False,False

if takeBoth:

    targetHit = a[(hit['reversal1'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal1'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)];
    targetMiss = a[(hit['reversal2'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal2'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)];

    targetIsHit,targetIsMiss = not targetHit.empty, not targetMiss.empty

else:

    targetHit = a[(hit['reversal1'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal1'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)];
    targetIsHit = not targetHit.empty
    if not targetIsHit:
         targetMiss = a[(hit['reversal2'].values==a['price'].values) & (hit['reversal2'].index.values<a['price'].index.values)]; 
         targetIsMiss = not targetMiss.empty

if targetIsHit:a.loc[hit.index.values,"target_hit"] = targetHit.index.values;
if targetIsMiss:a.loc[hit.index.values,"target_miss"] = targetMiss.index.values;
```

I do not get this error if `hit = a.ix[:,:-2].dropna()` only produces one row.  After reading about this I see that this is possibly due to the broadcasting rule.

Should I be iterating over the rows in `hit` to avoid this? Any other suggestions on how to fix this please?

Comment: The error occurs when you do `hit['reversal1'].values == a['price'].values`. You shouldn't do element-wise comparison like this (use e.g. `np.equals`) . In your specific case, though, I'd make sure that `hit['reversal1']` evaluates to a scalar, e.g. I'd replace `hit` by `hit.iloc[0]` to select only its first row.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do this @Kris?

Comment: Try `hit = hit.iloc[0]` in your second cell and then try to evaluate your third cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup it has to be for loop... Now I changed it to choose first from hit or miss.

```
import datetime,numpy as np,pandas as pd;
nan = np.nan;

a = pd.DataFrame(  {'price': {datetime.time(9, 0): 1,   datetime.time(10, 0): 0,   datetime.time(11, 0): 3,   datetime.time(12, 0): 4,   datetime.time(13, 0): 7,   datetime.time(14, 0): 6,   datetime.time(15, 0): 5,   datetime.time(16, 0): 4,   datetime.time(17, 0): 0,   datetime.time(18, 0): 2,   datetime.time(19, 0): 4,   datetime.time(20, 0): 7},  'reversal': {datetime.time(9, 0): 1,   datetime.time(10, 0): nan,   datetime.time(11, 0): nan,   datetime.time(12, 0): nan,   datetime.time(13, 0): nan,
  datetime.time(14, 0): 6.0,   datetime.time(15, 0): nan,   datetime.time(16, 0): nan,   datetime.time(17, 0): nan,   datetime.time(18, 0): nan,   datetime.time(19, 0): nan,   datetime.time(20, 0): nan}});


a['target_hit']=a['target_miss']=nan;
a['reversal1']=a['reversal']+1;
a['reversal2']=a['reversal']-a['reversal'];
a.sort_index(1,inplace=True);

hits = a.ix[:,:-2].dropna();

for row,hit in hits.iterrows():

        forwardRows = [row]<a['price'].index.values

        targetHit = a.index.values[(hit['reversal1']==a['price'].values) & forwardRows][0];
        targetMiss = a.index.values[(hit['reversal2']==a['price'].values) & forwardRows][0];

        if targetHit>targetMiss:
            a.loc[row,"target_miss"] = targetMiss;
        else:
            a.loc[row,"target_hit"] = targetHit;


print '#'*50
print a
'''
```

> ```
>     ##################################################
> ##################################################
>           price  reversal  reversal1  reversal2  target_hit target_miss
> 09:00:00      1       1.0        2.0        0.0         NaN    10:00:00
> 10:00:00      0       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 11:00:00      3       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 12:00:00      4       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 13:00:00      7       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 14:00:00      6       6.0        7.0        0.0         NaN    17:00:00
> 15:00:00      5       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 16:00:00      4       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 17:00:00      0       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 18:00:00      2       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 19:00:00      4       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> 20:00:00      7       NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
> ```

```
'''
```

Comment: Thanks again.  This answered my question.  I have another related question here if you get time to look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052132/modify-code-to-capture-values-greater-than-instead-of-exact-match